# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for deep inheritance

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application. My repository is written in the following way:

An interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyQueryRepository {

    int checkThis(String this);

    int checkThisAndThat(String this, String that);

}
```

An abstract Class:

```
public abstract class AbstractMyQueryRepository implements MyQueryRepository {

        @Override
        public int checkThis(String this) {...}

        @Override
        public int checkThisAndThat(String this, String that) {...}

}
```

then the implementation:

```
@Transactional(TVServiceDbConfigAtlanta.TV_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_NAME_ATLANTA)
@Repository
public class MyQueryRepositoryAtlanta extends AbstractMyQueryRepository {

  @Autowired
  public MyQueryRepositoryAtlanta (
          @Qualifier(TVServiceDbConfigAtlanta.TV_DATA_SOURCE_BEAN_NAME_ATLANTA) final DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource);
  }
}
```

When I try to autowire MyQueryRepositoryAtlanta in my UT in the following way:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class MyQueryRepositoryAtlantaTest{


    @Autowired
    private MyQueryRepositoryAtlanta myQueryRepositoryAtlanta ;

    @Test
    void checkThisTest() {
        assertThat(myQueryRepositoryAtlanta.checkThis("ABC")).isEqualTo(1);
    }


    @TestConfiguration
    @Profile("test")
    @Import(TVServiceDbConfigAtlanta.class)
    public static class Config {

    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'com.myapp.MyQueryRepositoryAtlantaTest': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'myQueryRepositoryAtlanta '; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.AbstractMyQueryRepository '
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE] [...]

I am not sure I understand why, since:

- The bean that I am testing is annotated as @Repository and
- There is no other bean called in the same way

I also checked similar answers in SOF but they are not applicable because of the particular structure that I use. Any idea about how to solve the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the bean is scanned in your test configuration?

Comment: Well, I have other 139 tests that work fine. How can I make sure if it's scanned?